# Local polynomial regression with Epanechnikov kernel

Tags: r, regression, self-study, nonparametric

I am trying to do local polynomial regression in R. The model I wish to fit has a single explanatory variable and a single response, it should have a bandwidth of 5, and a polynomial degree of 3.

I have looked through the reference manuals for packages: `np`, `kernsmooth`, and `locpol`. None of them seem to allow for this setup? Can someone suggest how to do this?

Comment: If the number of observations isn't large you can just write code to do it without worrying about making it efficient.

Comment: @Glen_b, I get that... But in my actual application I would like to have some data drive bandwidth selection, which I would very much like to avoid coding myself. Also it seems strange that, for instance, the np package does not have a solution for this, since it is otherwise very comprehensive

Comment: It looks to me like you can do this using npreg in the np package.  You can specify the Emanechnikov kernel with the parameters { ckertype="epanechnikov", ckerorder=2/4/6/8}, the bandwidth via the {bws} parameter, and construct your own basis for the local polynomial regression (working around the limitations, I admit.)  The bandwidth parameter can be a vector, so you can specify the appropriate bandwidth for each column of your basis.  I'm a little surprised that I couldn't find something more straightforward too.

Comment: @jbowman, yes but npreg only implements local constant and local linear methods. Not the polynomial way, at least that is the way I understand the documentation.

Comment: I was going through your post and came up to this. You might want to check the function `Lwls1D` from the package `fdapace`. I think it should do exactly what you describe. (I know this is *very* late to answer, I just knew the answer in a split second.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as far as I can tell there is no R function that really supports this.

This second best option is `locpoly` from the `kernsmooth` package:

```
local_polynomial <- locpoly(y = data$y, x = data$x, degree = 3, bandwidth = 5,          
                            kernel = "Epanechnikov")
```

Should in theory do the trick, I say "in theory" since the argument `kernel` is silently ignored by the function (so nice, NOT!). It will always fit with a Gaussian kernel (at least in the current version on CRAN).

Other than this, one would have to follow @Glen_b advice and code something from null.

Comment: Or use other software... For example, Stata's `lpoly` supports your preferences directly.

Comment: Yes, but my question was about R. So I do not feel that the answer "switch to Stata" is at all a good answer.

Comment: It's not an answer; it's a comment. You're totally entitled to regard it as not at all what you are asking, but the main point about a forum is that material may be of use or interest to others; and others here do use other software.   More crucially, I regard the entire question as off-topic here in any case as a software-specific question  and have already voted to close. So, without hostility, but it bites both ways; if my comment is off question, it underlines that by insisting on R solutions your question is off topic. But still interesting to me....